# How to use `Me` in vb.net With...End With block

Tags: .net, vb.net, instance, with-statement

With this code "VB.Net 2005"

```
Dim dep as new Department
With dep.AddNewEmployee()
   .FirstName = "Mr. A"
   .LastName = "B"
   If TypeOf {dep.AddNewEmployee()'s instance} is Serializable then
      'Do something
   End If
end With
```

in `{dep.AddNewEmployee()'s instance}` is there any syntax for this code.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do that by using the `With` syntax. You could just add a local variable that references the new object though:

```
Dim dep as new Department
Dim emp = dep.AddNewEmployee()
With emp
   .FirstName = "Mr. A"
   .LastName = "B"
   If emp.GetType().IsSerializable Then
      'Do something
   End If
end With
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way :

```
With dep.AddNewEmployee()
   .FirstName = "Mr. A"
   .LastName = "B"
   If .GetType().IsSerializable Then
      'Do something'
   End If
end With
```